# How to make either all fields in a object required for filling or none of the fields in a object to be filled at all?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, yup, react-hook-form

What I want is either all fields in IT head contact were filled or none of them to be filled. So for example if in IT head contact object First name, Last name fields were filled and email, phone number were not filled then error message would be displayed:"You should fill either all fields in IT head contact or none of them". And if all fields in IT head contact were filled or not filled then no error message would be displayed. Is it possible to implement with yup? I will provide code below image

[image: example]

Here is final interface of object that will be sent to backend:

```
interface Contact{
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    phone: string;
}

export interface ICompanyCreation {
    name: string;
    status: Status;
    country: string;
    city: string;
    address: string;
    zipCode: number;
    admin: Contact;
    itHead: Contact;
    customerManager: Contact;
}
```

Here is my yup validation schema:

```
export const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({

    name: yup.string().matches(nameRegEx, nameMessage).required(requiredMessage).trim(),
    country: yup.string().matches(countryRegEx,countryMessage).required(requiredMessage).trim(),
    city: yup.string().matches(nameRegEx, nameMessage).required(requiredMessage).trim(),
    address: yup.string().required(requiredMessage).trim(),
    zipCode: yup.number().positive(positiveNumberMessage).integer(integerNumberMessage).required(requiredMessage).typeError(numberMessage),

    admin: object().shape(
        {
            firstName: yup.string().matches(nameRegEx, nameMessage).required(requiredMessage).trim(),
            lastName: yup.string().matches(nameRegEx, nameMessage).required(requiredMessage).trim(),
            phone: yup.string().matches(phoneRegEx, phoneMessage).required(requiredMessage).trim(),
            email: yup.string().email(emailMessage).required(requiredMessage).trim(),
        }
    ),
    itHead: object().shape(
        {
            firstName: yup.string().matches(nameRegEx, nameMessage).required(requiredMessage).trim(),
            lastName: yup.string().matches(nameRegEx, nameMessage).required(requiredMessage).trim(),
            phone: yup.string().matches(phoneRegEx, phoneMessage).required(requiredMessage).trim(),
            email: yup.string().email(emailMessage).required(requiredMessage).trim(),
        }
    ),
    customerManager: object().shape(
        {
            firstName: yup.string().matches(nameRegEx, nameMessage).required(requiredMessage).trim(),
            lastName: yup.string().matches(nameRegEx, nameMessage).required(requiredMessage).trim(),
            phone: yup.string().matches(phoneRegEx, phoneMessage).required(requiredMessage).trim(),
            email: yup.string().email(emailMessage).required(requiredMessage).trim(),
        }
    ),
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your `itHead` validation schema like the one below. The idea is to check if any field except itself has some value. If so then the field itself will also be marked as *required*.
Note that passing ***normal function*** instead of ***arrow function*** gives you access to *siblings* properties. Also note that I have used `nameRegEx` for all the field so please replace it with respective regex.

```
itHead: Yup.object().shape({
      firstName: Yup.string().test(
        "first-name-test",
        "Please provide last name",
        function (value) {
          const { lastName, phone, email } = this.parent;
          if (lastName || phone || email) {
            return value && nameRegEx.test(value);
          }
          return true;
        }
      ),
      lastName: Yup.string()
        .trim()
        .test("last-name-test", "Please provide last name", function (value) {
          const { firstName, phone, email } = this.parent;
          if (firstName || phone || email) {
            return value && nameRegEx.test(value);
          }
          return true;
        }),
      phone: Yup.string().test(
        "phone-test",
        "Please provide phone",
        function (value) {
          const { firstName, lastName, email } = this.parent;
          if (firstName || lastName || email) {
            return value && nameRegEx.test(value);
          }
          return true;
        }
      ),
      email: Yup.string().test(
        "email-test",
        "Please provide email",
        function (value) {
          const { firstName, phone, lastName } = this.parent;
          if (firstName || phone || lastName) {
            return value && nameRegEx.test(value);
          }
          return true;
        }
      )
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way to implement it with when:

```
itHead: yup.object().shape(
        {
            firstName: yup.string().when(['lastName', 'phone', 'email'], {
                    is: (lastName: string|undefined, phone: string|undefined, email: string|undefined) => {
                        return (!lastName) && (!phone) && (!email);
                    },
                    then: yup.string().notRequired(),
                    otherwise: yup.string().matches(nameRegEx, nameMessage).required(requiredMessage).trim()
                }
            ),
            lastName: yup.string().when(
                ['firstName', 'phone', 'email'],{
                    is: (firstName: string|undefined, phone: string|undefined, email: string|undefined) => {
                        return (!firstName) && (!phone) && (!email);
                    },
                    then: yup.string().notRequired(),
                    otherwise: yup.string().matches(nameRegEx, nameMessage).required(requiredMessage).trim()
                }
            ),
            phone: yup.string().when(
                ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email'],{
                    is: (firstName: string|undefined, lastName: string|undefined, email: string|undefined) => {
                        return (!firstName) && (!lastName) && (!email);
                    },
                    then: yup.string().notRequired(),
                    otherwise: yup.string().matches(phoneRegEx, phoneMessage).required(requiredMessage).trim()
                }
            ),
            email: yup.string().when(
                ['firstName', 'lastName', 'phone'],{
                    is: (firstName: string|undefined, lastName: string|undefined, phone: string|undefined) => {
                        return (!firstName) && (!lastName) && (!phone);
                    },
                    then: yup.string().notRequired(),
                    otherwise: yup.string().email(emailMessage).required(requiredMessage).trim()
                }
            ),
        }, [['firstName', 'lastName'],  ['firstName', 'phone'], ['firstName', 'email'], ['lastName', 'phone'],  ['lastName', 'email'], ['phone', 'email']]
    )
```

Comment: Won't this cause cyclic dependency error by Yup

Comment: It would cause CDE if exhaustive array ( С(2,n) where n is number of properties depending on each other ) were not specified as second argument of shape method